# Django SMTP library generates wrong smtp auth plain authentication string

Tags: python, django, smtp

I encounter a strange, reproducible issue on different setups (localhost, production systems) with Django's smtp library:

the auth plain authentication string is totally off the mark. This is what the python console returns:

`sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=5, micro=0, releaselevel='final', serial=0)`


`from email.base64mime import body_encode as encode_base64
encode_base64(("\0%s\0%s" % ("User Name", "1234123241-23421334")).encode("ascii"), eol='')
'AFVzZXIgTmFtZQAxMjM0MTIzMjQxLTIzNDIxMzM0'`

However when I send email through python's smtplib.py this is the auth plain authentication string that is generated by smtplib.py:

`AFVzZXIgTmFtZQBiJzEyMzQxMjMyNDEtMjM0MjEzMzQn`

It's generated here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/smtplib.py#L629

Example: https://gist.github.com/macolo/bf2811c14d985d013dda0741bfd339e0

I am in dire need of a clue regarding this, thank you.

Comment: By the way: Isnt it also very strange how smtplib.py behaves after `AUTH PLAIN` fails? It should send `AUTH LOGIN` but totally omits it.

Comment: It seems that the password is formatted as a byte literal while the username is formatted as a string literal. When both types are stringed together the following happens:

echo -ne "\0User Name\0b'1234123241-23421334'" | base64
AFVzZXIgTmFtZQBiJzEyMzQxMjMyNDEtMjM0MjEzMzQn

Comment: Tracked the problem down to ascii encoding in https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-emailsettings/blob/master/aldryn_config.py#L30

Answer (score 0):

aldryn-emailsettings is being deprecated and it does not support python3 yet. Use a recent version of aldryn-django (1.8.15.2 or 1.9.8.2 and higher) and set the email connection as an `EMAIL_URL` environment variable instead.
See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dj-email-url/ for the supported backends.